# Javascript unmaximize browser

Tags: javascript, browser, window-resize

On click, unmaximize current browser.

`resizeTo()` apparently doesn't work for open tabs on chrome (correct me if I'm wrong).

Was wondering if there was a way to manipulate the window itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only manipulate a window if you opened it yourself (i.e., via `window.open()`).

You could open a copy of the current window by doing this:

```
var popup = window.open(window.location);
popup.resizeTo(250, 250);
```

This is for security and user convenience. This way, it's very difficult to create a website that jumps around your screen as soon as it is opened, for example, which would annoy users a *lot*.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=100, height=100");  // Opens a new window
myWindow.resizeTo(250, 250);                             // Resizes the new window
```

The resizeTo method for current browser window is disabled by default in several browsers, and I know that it can also be manually disabled in Firefox.
It has been widely misused, so most browser vendors feel that it should be disabled, or at least a user controllable option.

Comment: specified 'current' browser and 'window itself'